# set extended ImageView width and height programatically - android

Tags: android, height, width, imageview

I have a custom class that extends ImageView that I'm programatically putting on to a RelativeLayout.  I want each one of these images to be a specific width and height.  I've tried setting the width/height in code with LayoutParams and with setMaxWidth/setMaxHeight...neither seem to be working.

Here is the code from the constructor of the class:

```
LayoutParams p = new LayoutParams(50,67);       
        this.setLayoutParams(p);
        this.setImageResource(WhichImage(wi));
        this.setMaxWidth(50);
        this.setMaxHeight(67);
```

I've moved the call to setImageResource() above and below everything there and it still defaults to the true image size in my drawables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to tell the `ImageView` how to scale. Try using [`ImageView#setScaleType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setScaleType(android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType)).